# Jquery replace a string of html

Tags: jquery, regex, string, replace

This type of question has probably been asked before, but I cannot get the specific variation I need to work. Using jquery, I just need to have the output html automatically change when the page first loads, without user interaction.

So, I'm stuck with this html that I cannot modify:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="A" class="fullProfile">View Full Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="author" class="extLink">Laboratory Page</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need all of the above to change to just:

`<a name="A" class="letter">A</a>`

As you might guess, I'll need to ultimately repeat this 26 times (so I have anchor links for every letter), so something lite and efficient that I can easily repeat would be great.

A jsfiddle or similar would be ideal, showing what I need to put in the `<head>` of my document as I'm definitely not jquery proficient!

Thanks,
Dar.

Comment: Set up the jsfiddle and people will be more likely to help you out

Comment: `$('ul').html('new html');` perhaps? *Edit:* Might need to call parent before: `$('ul').parent().html('new html');`.

Comment: agree with reekogi, setup the scenario in JSFiddle with a good code example

Answer (score 1):

target all `.fullProfile` links, get the `href`, as it seems like that should be the name of the anchor, and replace the closest wrapping `UL` with the new anchor :

```
$('.fullProfile').each(function() {
    var new_anchor = $('<a />', {name   : $(this).attr('href'), 
                                 'class':'letter',
                                 text   : $(this).attr('href')
                                });
    $(this).closest('ul').replaceWith(new_anchor);
});
```

Comment: @mplungjan - no, only `prop()` or `this.href` does that, not `attr()` or `getAttribute`, so this works just like it is.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Seems our solutions are very similar :) +1

Comment: I think I deserve a +1 now too. No?

Comment: @mplungjan - yes you do, +1 !

Answer (score 1):

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/2pX82/)

```
$(function() {
    $(".fullProfile").each(function() {
      var href= $(this).attr("href");
      var link = $('<a name="'+href+'" class="letter">'+href+'</a>');
      $(this).closest("ul").replaceWith(link);
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Handling your other links to point at the new anchors:

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/LxrMa/)

```
$(function() {
  $(".fullProfile").each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    var link = $('<a name="'+href+'" class="letter">'+href+'</a>');
    $(this).closest("ul").replaceWith(link);
  });
  $(".cwyFellowName a").each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    if (href.length==1) $(this).attr("href","#"+href);
  });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Here we handle the rest of the links that do not have their own letter

```
 $(function() {
    $(".fullProfile").each(function() {
      var href = $(this).attr("href");
      var link = $('<a name="'+href+'" class="letter">'+href+'</a>');
      $(this).closest("ul").replaceWith(link);
    });
    $(".cwyFellowName a").each(function() {
      var href = $(this).attr("href");
      if (href.length==1) $(this).attr("href","#"+href);
      else if (href=="link") {
        var txt = $(this).text();
        if (txt.length==1) {
          $(this).attr("href","#"+txt);
          var nextDiv = $(this).parent().nextAll(".cwyFellowLinks:first");
          nextDiv.find("a").attr("name",txt).text(txt);
        }
      }    
   });
});
```

Comment: You realize that the reason you need to split and splice is because you're getting the href property, and not the attribute ?

Comment: I changed to prop, because I had the same issue with attr, must have missed something. Thanks

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks for your reply.
I've added your code directly to my demo page here:
http://www.ucd.ie/research/sandbox/conway/fellows/07.html
I'm just going to note the issues in a moment...

Comment: You need to change `<a href="A">A</a>` to `<a href="#A">A</a>` for it to work - see http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/LxrMa/ for an example with your html

Comment: You might see on my page now that A,B,C & D anchor links are working only. Also the extra code I wish to remove is still visible.

Comment: Your page works for me with the top links for at least Link C. You will need more code if you want to target the named anchor from a URL

Comment: @mplungjan If only I could add anchor links directly. Unfortunately, I cannot (as this data is pulled from an RSS feed I do not own). I can only edit the head of this page.

Comment: @mplungjan I've just added your updated code - thanks again. 
http://www.ucd.ie/research/sandbox/conway/fellows/07.html

Looks like I still only have A to D working. Also, "View full profile" is now broken for people who do have a real link.

I've added a line of css to enlarge links with the 'letter' class.

I'd be delighted with just getting A working ok. Then I could just repeat 26 times. Would that make it any easier?

Comment: Please see update. E and onwards did not work because there is no E in the `<ul> <li><a href="link" class="fullProfile">View Full Profile</a></li> <li><a href="author" class="extLink">Laboratory Page</a></li> </ul>`

Comment: @mplungjan Ah, I'm so sorry. I've since manually republished the rss and now have the correct body content being output. All my anchor links work now. I still have the issue of duplication though. Is there anything I can do to hide this and hide 'Keywords' & 'Description'? I really appreciate your time with all this.

Comment: My email is in my profile. This is no longer answering questions :)

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks. Couldn't see your email. Just sent you a short note via the form on your website.

Comment: @mplungjan Just to add, I've now updated my page to include your latest code:
http://www.ucd.ie/research/sandbox/conway/fellows/07.html

I still see two issues: the letters are duplicated and 'View my Profile' text is not showing, instead it shows a url that is not active.

Answer (score 0):

Something like...

```
 $("ul a").each(function (){
    $(this).html($(this).attr('href'));

    $(this).attr('class', 'letter');
    $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('href'));
    $(this).removeAttr('href');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gf4Qh/1/

You can play with selector, and values :)

Comment: Wouldn't this just change both anchors and keep the unordered list ?

Comment: _I need all of the above to change to just..._

Answer (score -1):

What about this?

http://jsfiddle.net/srU5w/3/

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('ul').each(function(){         

     var letter = 'not found';

     $(this).find('.fullProfile').each(function(){
         letter = $(this).attr('href');
     });

     $(this).replaceWith('<a name="'+letter+'" class="letter">'+letter+'</a><br/>');
 });
```

});

Comment: @mplungjan Ok, my fault. Just edited another time. Now it should be ok.

Comment: Now it is likely ALMOST working but with a needless `find` since you do not target the link with the information. However there are many other ULs in his page which also have links which are NOT author

Comment: @netblognet Thanks for your code. I have added it to my HEAD. Unfortunately, I now get this:
www.ucd.ie/research/sandbox/conway/fellows/08.html

Comment: I should have explicitly stated that I cannot touch the body code. It's pulled from an RSS feed that I do not own. Thanks.

Comment: @user2291964 Please refresh this stackoverflow thread. I edited my snippet and you have used an old code from an old answer of mine.

Comment: @netblognet That's updated now. It doesn't appear to work. I noticed my when I pasted it in my code editorsaid there was now a syntax error with my Google Analytics code. I haven't see that before.

Comment: I don't see any errors at the site you posted. Seems to me like it's working. What exactly doesn't work correct?

Comment: www.ucd.ie/research/sandbox/conway/fellows/08.html
With your code on the above page the anchor links don't work and the words: 'keywords' and 'description' is still visible.